# Vue js returning wrong element height

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to get the height of an image/element, this is what I did:

```
mounted() {
   this.infoHeight = this.$refs.info.clientHeight + 'px';
}
```

When I save then on hot reload it works, it gets the correct height but when I refresh the page it returns a smaller/wrong value. I also tried it on `created()` and it's the same. On other situations it doesn't even return anything.

**UPDATE (Temporary solution?)**

```
mounted() {
       setTimeout(() => this.infoHeight = this.$refs.info.clientHeight + 'px', 100);
}
```

I also tried using `window.addEventListener('load', () => //todo)` but on some components it worked and on others it didn't.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm running into the exact same issue and using setTimeout in mounted fixed it for me too, now I get consistent heights when hot reloading and refreshing.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, this is working while nextTick don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) which will execute after DOM update.

```
mounted() {
   this.$nextTick(() => { this.infoHeight = this.$refs.info.clientHeight + 'px' });
}
```

Comment: same problem, on hot reload it works but as soon as I refresh I get the wrong height.

Comment: @KevinBryan : try with computed property then

Comment: Same problem. Very weird that such a popular framework like Vue.js have this kind of bug.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this now in a way cleaner fashion using a [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

```
  data: () => ({
    infoHeight: 0,
    resizeObserver: null
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(this.onResize)
    this.resizeObserver.observe(this.$refs.info)
    this.onResize()
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    this.resizeObserver.unobserve(this.$refs.info)
  },
  methods: {
    onResize() {
      this.infoHeight = this.$refs.info.clientHeight + 'px'
    }
  }
```

Comment: This one actually worked for me. Using `addEventListener` on the window worked on resize but not on the initial load. This should ideally be the top answer.

Comment: Stumbled upon this thread and this answer after along search and have to say, that the `ResizeObserver` helped me as well!
In my case, I am watching `this.$root.$el` which has a height 0 after the first mount as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `this.$watch` with `immediate:true` option :

```
  mounted () {
    this.$watch(
        () => {
            return this.$refs.info
        },
      (val) => {
        this.infoHeight = this.$refs.info.clientHeight + 'px'
      },
      {
        immediate:true,
        deep:true
       }
    )
  }
```

The above solution works only in the initial mount, the following one use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver)

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    infoHeight: 0,
    observer: null,

    img: "https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/6TOyJZTDnuutGpSMYcFlfZ/4dfab047c1d94bbefb0f9325c54e08a2/01-nature_668593321.jpg?fit=fill&w=480&h=270"

  }),
  mounted() {
    const config = {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    };
    this.observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation) {
          this.infoHeight = this.$refs.info.clientHeight + 'px'
          console.log(" changed ", this.$refs.info.clientHeight)
        }
      });
    });
    this.observer.observe(this.$refs.info, config);


  },

  methods: {
    changeImg() {
      this.img = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a7/3d/6e/a73d6e4ac85c6a822841e449b24c78e1.jpg"
    },

  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <p>{{infoHeight}}</p>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="changeImg">Change image</button>
  <div ref="info">
    <img :src="img" alt="image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't going to work because the clientHeight is not a reactive property and a change won't be noticed by Vue.

Comment: thank you for your comment I'll try to find a working solution and I'll let you know